# Convert hex string to int

Tags: java, hex

I am trying to convert a string that is 8 characters long of hex code into an integer so that I can do int comparison instead of string comparisons over a lot of different values.

I know this is fairly trivial in C++ but I need to do it in Java.  The test case I need to satisfy is essentially to Convert "AA0F245C" to int and then back to that string so that I know it is converting right.

I have tried the following:

```
int decode = Integer.decode("0xAA0F245C");  // NumberFormatException
int decode2 = Integer.decode("AA0F245C"); //NumberFormatException
int parseInt = Integer.parseInt("AA0F245C", 16); //NumberFormatException
int valueOf = Integer.valueOf("AA0F245C", 16); //NumberFormatException
```

I have also tried doing it two characters at a time and multiplying the results, which the conversion works but the number is not right.

```
int id = 0;
for (int h = 0; h < hex.length(); h= h+2)
{
    String sub = hex.subSequence(h, h+2).toString();

if (id == 0)
    id = Integer.valueOf(sub, 16);
else
    id *= Integer.valueOf(sub, 16);             
 }
//ID = 8445600 which = 80DEA0 if I convert it back.
```

I can not use third party libraries just so you know, so this has to be done in Java standard libraries.

Thank you for your help in advance.

Comment: You are multiplying when you should be shifting.

Comment: `0xAA0F245C = 2853119068` but `Integer.MAX_VALUE = 0x7fffffff = 2147483647`

Comment: I know the question has been around for two years. However, java 8 enables another solution. They added the `Integer.parseUnsignedInt("value",radix)` method which serves your purpose. If the value is greater than `Integer.MAX_VALUE` it is mapped to a negative number.

Answer (score 177, accepted):

It's simply too big for an int (which is 4 bytes and signed).

Use

```
Long.parseLong("AA0F245C", 16);
```

Comment: Awesome thank you! I probably should have known that.  But it makes me feel better none of the 4 people I asked prior to posting knew it either :).  As a side note, I now have to go figure out why the person wrote the code that I need to compare the ints to has them as ints and not longs... which probably means something else is off.  That's besides the point... thank you for the quick answer!!!!  Also curse you java for your terrible error message... "It's to big" would have been helpful.

Comment: When I try with big hex string, I get `NumberFormatException: For input string: "AF0005E2A6C630059E4754B8799360F5"` ... Solution ?

Comment: @AnumSheraz you don't want to convert to a long but to a byte array. See for example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/140131/convert-a-string-representation-of-a-hex-dump-to-a-byte-array-using-java

Comment: An alternative to converting to a byte array for a large number is to use the `BigInteger` class like this: `BigInteger value = new BigInteger(valueString, 16)`

Answer (score 57):

you may use like that

```
System.out.println(Integer.decode("0x4d2"))    // output 1234
//and vice versa 
System.out.println(Integer.toHexString(1234); //  output is 4d2);
```

Comment: i like this answer, didn't know there is a generic, typeinsensitive method for this in the Integer class. thanks for the knowledge.

Comment: Same here, I wish I could upvote this 5 more times.

Answer (score 21):

The maximum value that a Java `Integer` can handle is 2147483657, or 2^31-1.  The hexadecimal number AA0F245C is 2853119068 as a decimal number, and is far too large, so you need to use

```
Long.parseLong("AA0F245C", 16);
```

to make it work.

Comment: off: interesting that a more detailed answer albeit 5 minutes later gets only 1 upvote compared to 14. Although true, this one didn't say magical '4 bytes' and 'signed'...hm.

Answer (score 15):

you can easily do it with parseInt with format parameter.

```
Integer.parseInt("-FF", 16) ; // returns -255
```

[javadoc Integer](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt(java.lang.String,%20int))

Comment: the link is broken

Answer (score 9):

This is the right answer:

`myPassedColor = "#ffff8c85"
int colorInt = Color.parseColor(myPassedColor)`

Comment: This is (evidently) referring to `android.graphics.Color` - `java.awt.Color` does not have a `parseColor` method. Nothing in the question indicates it is reasonable to presume presence of android libraries. This answer should have nowhere near this many upvotes.

Answer (score 4):

An additional option to the ones suggested, is to use the `BigInteger` class. Since hex values are often large numbers, such as sha256 or sha512 values, they will easily overflow an `int` and a `long`. While converting to a byte array is an option as other answers show, `BigInterger`, the often forgotten class in java, is an option as well.

```
String sha256 = "65f4b384672c2776116d8d6533c69d4b19d140ddec5c191ea4d2cfad7d025ca2";
BigInteger value = new BigInteger(sha256, 16);
System.out.println("value = " + value);
// 46115947372890196580627454674591875001875183744738980595815219240926424751266
```

Answer (score 3):

For those of you who need to convert hexadecimal representation of a signed byte from two-character String into byte (which in Java is always signed), there is an example. Parsing a hexadecimal string never gives negative number, which is faulty, because 0xFF is -1 from some point of view (two's complement coding). The principle is to parse the incoming String as int, which is larger than byte, and then wrap around negative numbers.
I'm showing only bytes, so that example is short enough.

```
String inputTwoCharHex="FE"; //whatever your microcontroller data is

int i=Integer.parseInt(inputTwoCharHex,16);
//negative numbers is i now look like 128...255

// shortly i>=128
if (i>=Integer.parseInt("80",16)){

    //need to wrap-around negative numbers
    //we know that FF is 255 which is -1
    //and FE is 254 which is -2 and so on
    i=-1-Integer.parseInt("FF",16)+i;
    //shortly i=-256+i;
}
byte b=(byte)i;
//b is now surely between -128 and +127
```

This can be edited to process longer numbers. Just add more FF's or 00's respectively. For parsing 8 hex-character signed integers, you need to use Long.parseLong, because FFFF-FFFF, which is integer -1, wouldn't fit into Integer when represented as a positive number (gives 4294967295). So you need Long to store it. After conversion to negative number and casting back to Integer, it will fit. There is no 8 character hex string, that wouldn't fit integer in the end.

Answer (score 1):

```
//Method for Smaller Number Range:
Integer.parseInt("abc",16);

//Method for Bigger Number Range.
Long.parseLong("abc",16);

//Method for Biggest Number Range.
new BigInteger("abc",16);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with this:

long abc=convertString2Hex("1A2A3B");

```
private  long  convertString2Hex(String numberHexString)
{
    char[] ChaArray = numberHexString.toCharArray();
    long HexSum=0;
    long cChar =0;

    for(int i=0;i<numberHexString.length();i++ )
    {
        if( (ChaArray[i]>='0') && (ChaArray[i]<='9') )
            cChar = ChaArray[i] - '0';
        else
            cChar = ChaArray[i]-'A'+10;
        HexSum = 16 * HexSum + cChar;
    }
    return  HexSum;
}
```