# Why is my program crashing (java)?

Tags: java, methods, crash, hex, decimal

I need to convert hexadecimal to decimal using different methods. When I enter numbers that are correct hexadecimal numbers, my program displays the decimal value and says that the number is valid. However, when I enter incorrect hexadecimal values, my program crashes.
Here is my code:

```
import java.io.*;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class pg3a {

 public static void main(String[] args)  throws IOException {

   Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

     String hex;
     char choice = 'y';
     boolean isValid = false;
  do {
     System.out.print("Do you want to enter a hexadecimal number? ");
     System.out.print("y or n?: ");
     choice = keyboard.next().charAt(0);
 switch(choice){
    case 'y':
      System.out.print("Enter a hexadecimal number: #");
      hex = keyboard.next();
      hex = hex.toUpperCase();
      int hexLength = hex.length();
      isValid = valid(hex);
      Integer value = Integer.parseInt(hex,16);
      System.out.println("The value: " + value);

   if (isValid) {
      System.out.println(hex + " is valid");
  }
   break;
  case 'n':
      System.out.print("Quit");
  }
  }while (choice != 'n');
  }

public static boolean valid (String validString) {

  int a = 0;
  if (validString.charAt(0) == '-') {
  a = 1;
  }
    for (int i=a; i< validString.length(); i++) {
       if (!((validString.charAt(i) >= 'A' && validString.charAt(i) <= 'F')|| (validString.charAt(i) >= 0 && validString.charAt(i) <= 9)))
   {
   return false;
   }
   }
   return true;
   }


  public static long convert (String hexValue) {

    long decimal = 0;
    boolean isNegative = false;
    int a = 0;

    if (hexValue.charAt(0) == '-') {
    isNegative = true;
    a = 1;
   }
   for (int i = a; i<hexValue.length(); i++) {
      decimal = decimal*16;
        if (hexValue.charAt(i) >= '0' && hexValue.charAt(i) <= '9') {
        decimal += hexValue.charAt(i) - '0';
     }
       else if (hexValue.charAt(i) >= 'a' && hexValue.charAt(i) <= 'f') {
          decimal += hexValue.charAt(i) - 'a' + 10;
     }
     }
       if (isNegative == true) {
         decimal *= -1;
    }
    return decimal;
    }
    }
```

why is it crashing and how can I fix it so that it displays "invalid" when incorrect hexadecimal digits are entered?

Comment: Post the Stacktrace, please.

Comment: And you do not allow negative hex-values < 16 ?

Comment: why do all this? Put a try-catch around the parseInt call and catch `NumberFormatException`

Comment: @RonE just as _someone_ suggeted it at [OPs previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19130604/printing-out-variables-from-different-methods-in-java)

Answer (score 1):

If you enter an invalid hex number, `Integer.parseInt()` will throw `NumberFormatException`. Change your code like this:

```
...
isValid = valid(hex);

if (isValid) {
    Integer value = Integer.parseInt(hex,16);
    System.out.println("The value: " + value);
    System.out.println(hex + " is valid");
}
...
```

Comment: When I do this, the program doesn't crash anymore (so thank you!!!) but now when I enter a valid hex number, it shows up with "invalid" instead of the value. Any idea why?

Comment: Check your `valid()` method.

Answer (score 0):

Add `Integer value = Integer.parseInt(hex,16);` inside if statement and print invalid in else block.

```
 if (isValid) {
       Integer value = Integer.parseInt(hex,16);
      System.out.println("The value: " + value);
      System.out.println(hex + " is valid");
  }
  else{
   System.out.println("invalid");
  }
```

**Updated:**

Change your valid method as follows:

```
    public static boolean valid(String validString) {

        int a = 0;
        if (validString.charAt(0) == '-') {
            a = 1;
        }
        for (int i = a; i < validString.length(); i++) {
//            if (!((validString.charAt(i) >= 'A' && validString.charAt(i) <= 'F') || (validString.charAt(i) >= 0 && validString.charAt(i) <= 9))) {
//                return false;
//            }
            char ch=validString.charAt(i);
            if(!(Character.isDigit(ch) || (Character.isLetter(ch) && ((ch-'A')<=5))) ){
            return false;
           }
        }
        return true;
    }
```

Comment: When I do this, the program doesn't crash anymore (so thank you!!!) but now when I enter a valid hex number, it shows up with "invalid" instead of the value. Any idea why?

Comment: Would you tell me which valid  value you entered?

Comment: I entered "123abc" which should work. How can I correct the result of isValid? I currently have it as a boolean set to false.

Answer (score 0):

```
do {
  System.out.print("Do you want to enter a hexadecimal number? ");
  System.out.print("y or n?: ");
  choice = keyboard.next().charAt(0);
  int base = 10;
  switch(choice)
  {
    case 'y':
      System.out.print("Enter a hexadecimal number: #");
      hex = keyboard.next();
      hex = hex.toUpperCase(); //I'm not sure if this step is necessary
      try {
          Integer value = Integer.parseInt(hex, 16);
          System.out.println("Valid hex format");
          System.out.println("Hex: " + hex);
          System.out.println("Decimal: " + value);

      }
      catch (NumberFormatException e) {
          System.out.println("Invalid hex format");
          System.out.println("Input: " + hex);
      }
      break;
    case 'n':
      System.out.print("Quit");
      break
  }
} while (choice != 'n');
```

Now you can delete all your helper methods

Answer (score 0):

Your program is crashing because you are not handling the exception that is thrown when an invalid hexadecimal value is entered. The `Integer.parseInt()` method throws a `NumberFormatException` if the string it is passed cannot be parsed as a number. In your code, you are not checking for this exception, so your program will crash if an invalid hexadecimal value is entered.

To fix this, you can add a try-catch block around the call to `Integer.parseInt()`. The try-catch block will catch the `NumberFormatException` and print a message indicating that the value is invalid.

Here is the modified code:

```java
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

  Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

  String hex;
  char choice = 'y';
  boolean isValid = false;

  do {
    System.out.print("Do you want to enter a hexadecimal number? ");
    System.out.print("y or n?: ");
    choice = keyboard.next().charAt(0);

    switch (choice) {
      case 'y':
        System.out.print("Enter a hexadecimal number: #");
        hex = keyboard.next();
        hex = hex.toUpperCase();
        int hexLength = hex.length();
        isValid = valid(hex);

        try {
          Integer value = Integer.parseInt(hex, 16);
          System.out.println("The value: " + value);

          if (isValid) {
            System.out.println(hex + " is valid");
          }
        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
          System.out.println(hex + " is invalid");
        }

        break;
      case 'n':
        System.out.print("Quit");
    }
  } while (choice != 'n');
}
```

This code will first check if the value entered is valid using the `valid()` method. If the value is valid, the `Integer.parseInt()` method will be called to convert the value to a decimal number. If the value is invalid, the `NumberFormatException` will be caught and a message will be printed indicating that the value is invalid.

Comment: Although this catches the exception, the main issue with the original posted code is that despite calling `valid(hex)` method to determine whether or not a String contains valid hex characters, the result of the valid method is ignored, and the String is parsed irrespective of whether or not it contains a valid hex string.