# Java: How to turn Hex into int?

Tags: java, numberformatexception, parseint

I'm working with `BufferedImage` (in PNG) and want to replace a colour with another.
I have all colours stored as strings for easy handling but...

```
for(int x=0;x<output.getWidth();x++)
    for(int y=0;y<output.getHeight();y++)
        if(output.getRGB(x,y)==Integer.parseInt("ffff00fe",16))
            output.setRGB(x,y,Integer.parseInt("ffaaaaaa",16));
```

the resultant integers should be negative numbers, but it throws `NumberFormatException`

when I do `output.getRGB(x,y)` it returns negative numbers on non-transparent pixels

Comment: possible duplicate of [Convert hex string to int](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11194513/convert-hex-string-to-int)

Comment: Are these strings coming from an external source?  Because if they're not, just use the hex literals `0xffff00fe` and `0xffaaaaaa`

Comment: Even if not, unless the strings are changing each time around the loop it would be better to hoist the conversion out of the loop. (The JIT *may* be smart enough to do that, but I wouldn't count on that.) If you want to see the positive (unsigned) value for those pixels, you can also use `Integer.toUnsignedString(output.getRGB(x, y))` or `Integer.toUnsignedString(output.getRGB(x, y), 16)`.

Comment: `0xffff00fe` _is_ a negative number when interpreted as a 32-bit int.  What is the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Values greater that `0x7fff_ffff` are too large to be handled as signed `ints.` Java 8 has added methods for dealing with `ints` as if they contained unsigned values. Simply replace `parseInt` with `parseUnsignedInt:`

```
Integer.parseUnsignedInt("ffaaaaaa", 16)
```

If you need to work with Java 7 and earlier, you can parse it as a `long` and then cast it to `int.` Or, if the values are constants, you can write them as numeric constants such as `0xffaaaaaa` or even `0xffaa_aaaa` and avoid dealing with string conversions (the underscores in numbers are allowed since Java 7 and can make them much easier to read).

Answer (score 3):

You could do

```
int number = (int)Long.parseLong("ffff00fe", 16);
```

Comment: this is awkward, last time I tried it didn't work, but now it did, thanks

Answer (score 0):

The number 2,147,483,647 (or hexadecimal 7FFFFFFF) is the maximum positive value for a 32-bit signed binary **integer**. What you're trying to convert is something almost double that, which means the first bit of the binary number is a 1; in a signed binary integer the first bit being a 1 means it's a negative number.

Basically, you need something bigger to parse it.
Try `(int) Long.parseLong("ffff00fe", 16)` instead of `Integer.parseInt("ffff00fe",16)`