# How convert string with hex characters convert to human readable value of that hex

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-activity

I am newbie in android/java. I'd like to show a human-readable string of a hex value in a CharSequence on a EditText. [The code is here](https://github.com/ikarus23/MifareClassicTool/blob/master/Mifare%20Classic%20Tool/app/src/main/java/de/syss/MifareClassicTool/Activities/DumpEditor.java#L582). This code shows the string representation of the hex e.g:    `7465737420202020203f7465737420202020202020202020203f7465737420202020202020202020203fd3f7d3f7d3f77f078840ffffffffffff`

This is what I want to show:

```
test     ?test           ?test           ?Ó÷Ó÷Ó÷ˆ@ÿÿÿÿÿÿ
```

How should I do to convert hex value in text. I tried many convert ways but I either got runtime errors or a wrong characters.

Comment: Can you show what you tried?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Convert hex string to int](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11194513/convert-hex-string-to-int)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do like this:

```
    String a = " 7465737420202020203f7465737420202020202020202020203f7465737420202020202020202020203fd3f7d3f7d3f77f078840ffffffffffff";
    a = a.trim();
    StringBuffer result = new StringBuffer();

    for (int i = 0; i < a.length(); i+=2) {
        String sub = a.substring(i, i+2);
        int b = Integer.parseInt(sub, 16);
        result.append((char)b);
    }

    System.out.println(result);
```

This code takes in consideration that the original string will be always valid. There are no checkings.

It's the basic idea, hope it helps!

Comment: Use StringBuffer instead?