# Parse 0x format from plain string to bytes in Java

Tags: java, android, string

I need to change 
This (string):

```
"0xab,0xcd,0x00,0x01,0xff,0xff,0xab,0xcd,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x10,0x00,0x00,0x01,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00"
```

to (bytes)

```
[0xab,0xcd,0x00,0x01,0xff,0xff,0xab,0xcd,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x10,0x00,0x00,0x01,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00 ]
```

using java.

I've successfully implement that in swift.

```
// Your original string
let hexString = "0xab,0xcd,0x00,0x01,0xff,0xff,0xab,0xcd,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x10,0x00,0x00,0x01,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00"

// Remove all of the "0x"
let cleanString = hexString.replacingOccurrences(of: "0x", with: "")

// Create an array of hex strings
let hexStrings = cleanString.components(separatedBy: ",")

// Convert the array of hex strings into bytes (UInt8)
let bytes = hexStrings.flatMap { UInt8($0, radix: 16) }
```

Comment: Per your example, it looks like all you did was convert the comma delimited string into an array. Is this correct? All you might need to do is a string split on the comma character. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3413586/string-to-string-array-conversion-in-java

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the [String Doc](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/String.html), there are "split" and "replaceAll" methods. To convert String to hex value, have a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11194513/convert-hex-string-to-int).