# Convert String same as into Int in Android

Tags: android

I want to convert `String` into `int`.

For example:

if `String` is `"0x1F60A"` then it should be convert into `int` same as `0x1F60A`

```
String str = "0x1F60A";
int i = 0x1F60A; // it must be something like this.
```

Why I need this. Because I'm going to convert unicode int into Emoji 
I'm using this code.

```
final String emojiString = str.substring(start,end);
// value in emojiString is 0x1F60A
int unicode = // need to convert this string into int
ss.replace(start, end, new String(Character.toChars(unicode)));
```

Can you please let me know how can I do that.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert hex string to int](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11194513/convert-hex-string-to-int)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**For conversion of Unicode to Int:**

You have to omit the `2` first characters with `.substring(2)`

```
int code = Integer.parseInt(unicodeStr.substring(2), 16);
```

**For conversion of String to int:**

```
try {
    myNum = Integer.parseInt(myString);
} catch(NumberFormatException nfe) {
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int unicode = Integer.parseInt(emojiString.substring(2), 16);
```