# Java parse hexadecimal as a integer

Tags: javascript, java, parseint

When i paste  parseInt("3cf1bb13f1c96", 16) to javascript console, it successfuly converts to integer value which is 1072142774901910 but when i use Integer.parseInt("3cf1bb13f1c96", 16) in java it prints something

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "3cf1bb13f1c96"
    at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)
    at Main.example(Main.java:line)
    at Main.example(Main.java:line)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert hex string to int](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11194513/convert-hex-string-to-int)

Comment: This is in `Java` but why do you have a `Javascript` tag attached too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value you are parsing is out of Integer range. In Java, the integer ranges from -2,147,483,648 to +2,147,483,647 . Try to use Long instead:

```
 Long.parseLong("3cf1bb13f1c96", 16)
```

it parses successfully:

```
> Task :Foo.main()
1072142774901910
```

Comment: @ArvindKumarAvinash I already know it but i guess the one who need to learn how to do it is you because 10 minutes should pass before you can accept a answer

Comment: Oh...is it so? Thanks, @Garbarius for this information. I really didn't know it. Wish you success!